# How to make View appear when button is clicked in android

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

How is that possible? Thanks! Should I put my View (RelativeLayout) on-top another View and make it invisible and when the user clicks the button it sets it to visible? Or is there another easier way that opens a Dialog(?) in the middle of the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: I use the method of setting visibility. But you can wait for some more experts answers, If there is any other better way I will also be interested to know it.

Comment: You are talking about to open a dialog by button click? Why not using AlertDialog ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a layout to put the child view onto. Safest is Linear Layout since adding multiple child is easy

Fisrt create a xml file in layouts.

for eg in layout 
add a file named say iv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_iv"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/person_default_page" />
```

In the layout where you want to add create a linear layout with some it say @+id/Row_id
Then in the code when you need to add the view

```
LinearLayout ll = = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Row_id);
ll.removeAllViews();
View element = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.iv, ll, false);
ImageView image_iv = (ImageView) element.findViewById(R.id.ri_iv);
ll.addView(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it with an alert dialog. If you want to customize dialog use this
-First create an xml for your dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/header_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/username" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="@string/password"/>
```

and override this method

```
   @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
// Add action buttons
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // sign in the user ...
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
           }
       });      
return builder.create();
```

}

More info on [Devlopper android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)